# Constant variable not useable within img-src / View

Tags: angularjs

this is working :

```
<img src="{{'http://localhost:3000/'+club.img }}" class="photov"/>
```

But as soon as i define an app constant :

```
myApp.value('serverNodeUrl', 'http://localhost:3000/')
```

This is not working :

```
<img src="{{serverNodeUrl+club.img }}" class="photov"/>
```

I've correctly injected serverNodeUrl  inside of the controller and can do a console.log(serverNodeUrl).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one way binding, angularjs looks for your scope variable in your controller for values.

In your case, u might have injected your constant into the controller, but you have not set it to a scope variable. Thus, angularjs is unable to find a value for `serverNodeUrl` in `<img src="{{serverNodeUrl+club.img }}" class="photov"/>`

You might consider adding the following

```
$scope.serverNodeUrl = serverNodeUrl;
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Angular variable can be used inside the angular{{}} -It for binding the angular variables to the view(HTML)
2.For image please use ng-src="" 
So,
 your code works if

```
<img ng-src="http://localhost:3000/{{club.img}}" class="photov"/>
```

**NOTE:**Please Dont use + inside for concatination.